# How to integrate ProPay payment gateway to access Credit cards payment on eCommerce site into laravel 4.2 (php) project?

Tags: php, addition, payment-gateway, implementation, laravel-4.2

I am working on laravel 4.2 and I am developing eCommerce site. I want to integrate Propay (http://www.propay.com/) as Payment gateway on my site to access the Credit Cards Payment paid by customers after successful orders of products.

So, I have searched for this, but I am not getting any proper help from anywhere. May be I am missing something. But I have found one link for developer provided by Propay (https://developer.propay.com/). But it does not have proper documentation. Also, I am not able to create any testing account there(like we create sandbox account for paypal to test). For Propay integration, 2 things 'Account Number' and 'Certification String' are essential. From where we will get these details for testing purpose on staging or local server.

So how to proceed there? I am not clearly getting that doc.

Does anyone has implemented Propay in laravel-4.2 Or in plain PHP Or codeigniter? Is there any proper doc or link to refer?

Please help Me. And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

CakePHP 2.x wrapper plugin for ProPay API services. Uses auto generated WSDL.
https://packagist.org/packages/clawsonm/cakephp-propay